# TYPO3 frontend login creates encrypted password

Tags: mysql, security, authentication, typo3, frontend

For one of our TYPO3 6.1.7 websites it is vital that the passwords of frontend users (sr_feuser_register) are stored in plain text. In the installation tool, the security level has been set to normal:

```
[FE][loginSecurityLevel] = normal
```

But still I experience the following problem:

1. I create a new frontend user with a plain text password in MySQL.
2. I log in via the frontend - this works flawlessly.
3. I take a look at the MySQL database: suddenly the plain text password has been converted to an encrypted salted (?) password.

How do I deactivate this functionality? I don't want TYPO3 to mess with the plain text passwords in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Altough the installation tool calls "normal" the default value, "normal" is not the value of the loginSecurityLevel when this option is left empty:

```
[FE][loginSecurityLevel] =
```

This leaves the passwords in the database unchanged.